# How to do versioning of .ipynb by removing output and converting?

Tags: python, git, jupyter-notebook

I want to do versioning of ipynb notebooks such that, when I add the notebooks to git, the scripts that remove output and convert it to python script are called. Is there any way that I can automate this, so that when I put in the `git add .` command, it starts running the required scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a git `clean` filter:

```
echo '*.ipynb filter=notebook2python' >> .gitattributes
git config --global filter.notebook2python.clean /path/to/notebook2python/script
git config --global filter.notebook2python.smudge cat
```

More documentation in [Customizing Git - Git Attributes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a git hook for this: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this functionality.